# SSAS error when processing data, after picking the database table

Tags: sql-server, ssas

I'm trying to import a table from my SQL server, with analysis services tabular project. Both SQL server and SSAS is installed on my local machine.

I get the option to see the database' table, as the picture below shows.

[Display Options for connection with SQL server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqKPV.png)

But during processing it with the four windows options gives:

**impersonate service account** throws the error:

```
*Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 
'OLE DB or ODBC error: The credentials provided 
for the SQL source are invalid. (Source at desktop-ghgoehf;MyFuckingSQLDB.).
'.*
```

**Impersonate Identity** throws the error

```
  Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 
  'OLE DB or ODBC error: We're sorry, an error occurred during evaluation..
  '.
```

Impersonate Account, I can't even use. I got a windows user tho. But I'm getting the message *We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided. Please try again*

**Impersonate Unattended Account** throws the error

```
 Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 
'OLE DB or ODBC error: The credentials provided for
 the SQL source are invalid. (Source at desktop-ghgoehf;MyFuckingSQLDB.).
 '.
```

I have tried creating a user for the database, and given it all the permissions possible. But it cannot authenticate it when connecting with 'database'.

I have spend an entire day going through topics on the same issue, but I cannot find anything that has helped me. Some says it may per a permissions issue, but I am not sure how I'd start to debug that.

My database has the containment type set to Partial, which was something I read might help. But it did not for me.

If any information is missing that can help resolve this issue, please ask and I will provide it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is your SSAS Server and SQL Server in the same domain? What is the service account used by SSAS?

Comment: Are you using SSAS Tabular or Dimensional?

Comment: @Piotr Tabular. I'm not sure how I'd check which service account is used for SSAS. but both are on the same computer locally.

Comment: That is a nice DB Name used here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use "impersonate account" in this scenario.
For account name you need to use format: "Domain name\User account name". As I understand you are not joined to a domain, so type name of your computer instead of domain name, like "MyPc\MyUser" and then provide Windows password.

Comment: I have a domain, and a user name. "DESKTOP-GHGOEHF\Q300L" however I don't have a password. At least I never used one. I'm getting the error "We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided"

Comment: It was the issue with having no password, that's apparently required. Thanks for pointing the domain out! :)

Answer (score 0):

This YouTube video might be helpful. Need to go to the config of the SQL server to find "log on as" and then create a new login on the SQL server and then use "impersonate service account" to import the data source https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-uX5T8T5ovM